# iOS low memory warnings and simulator's "Simulate memory warning"

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, ios-simulator

Apps under iOS receive low memory warnings via these mechanisms:

- `[AppDelegate applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:]`
- `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`
- `[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning]`

What are the relationships between these items? Do they all occur when a low memory condition is received or do they have subtle differences? In what order are they executed?

In the simulator there is an option to "Simulate memory warnings". Does this do anything except for called `didReceiveMemoryWarning:` on all UIViewControllers?

I'm wanting to use the Xcode profiler tool to see what happens these days around images loaded by the caching `[UIImage imageNamed:]` method -- are they uncached? -- but I need to know how to 'properly' trigger low memory conditions -- even if it's just by allocating a whole lot of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your question about the `UIImage` cache for `imageNamed`, yes, it appears that it does purge the cache. Here I loaded 225 images via `imageNamed` and then, 20 seconds into the execution, I simulated a memory warning:

[image: allocations for imageNamed]

Having said that, I think the `imageNamed` cache is a blunt instrument, and I prefer to do my own cache via `NSCache`, so I can constrain how many images it should retain in the cache by setting `countLimit`, with the goal of preventing a memory warning at all. As an aside, while `NSCache` does not respond to `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`, it does automatically purge itself in real low memory situations. It will not, though, respond to manually simulating memory warning in the simulator.

Anyway, here is the log of loading images with a `NSCache`, first without the `countLimit` and secondly with a `countLimit` of 50, purging the cache at the end of each:

[image: NSCache without and with countLimit]

Comment: Thanks Rob. Interesting to see that 'simulate memory warning' does what it should -- I was worried it was a cosmetic fluffy option that just called didReceiveMemoryWarning and nothing else.

Comment: @occulus I don't blame you. I had the same concern when I first experimented with "simulate memory warning."

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

I've confirmed that on the simulator (iOS6.1 on iOS Simulator 6.0), "Simulate memory warning" causes all three mechanisms to be triggered, in this order:

1. `[AppDelegate applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:`
2. `[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning]`
3. `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`

Comment: Seems like UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification is not always triggered on older simulators (iOS 5 simulator in my case).